# Create a loop based on date Mysql

Tags: mysql, loops

I have a query :

```
insert into fookoo_business
select stat_date, sum(spend), sum(revenue)
from hooloo_business;
```

that i want to run for each date from '2017-01-20' until yesterday (it means the query will run 434 times if we're at 01/04/2018), for each date separately 
(in a loop).

how can i create a loop in Mysql to do it for me?

I have tried:

creating procedure for the query `select @stat_date, sum(spend), sum(revenue)`
I called 'query'

then :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE loop_procedure()

BEGIN

SET @stat_date='2018-03-20';

CALL 'query';

REPEAT
  SET @stat_date = @stat_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
UNTIL @stat_date = CURDATE() END REPEAT;



END
```

Comment: What is the problem with this logic?

Comment: @Shooki What is your expected insert for some missing dates ?

Answer (score 0):

eventually i've used the following logic within a stored procedure to fetch the data:

```
PROCEDURE `x_monitoring_loop`()
BEGIN

 DECLARE i INT;
 DECLARE len INT;
 SET len = 434;
 SET i = 0;
 WHILE (i < len) DO
 SET @stat_date= CURDATE()-INTERVAL 1 DAY;
 SET @stat_date= @stat_date- INTERVAL i DAY; 

 Insert query;

 SET i = i +1;
 END WHILE;
```

This way the query ran 434 times for each day, beginning at current date - 1 day.